# Flip image error occur with using simultaneous variable in opencv4nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to get opposite rotate value when the image is flipped.
I got opposite value but I got image undifined error an each time.
What is the wrong thing I did?

```
const cv = require('/opncvnode/node_modules/opencv4nodejs');
var rotate = 1;
var image = cv.imread('lenna.png');

function flip(image, rotate){
    var flip_img = image.flip(1);
    var rotate = -(rotate);
    return flip_img, rotate;
}

function imageAugmentation(image, rotate){

    var image, rotate = flip(image, rotate);
    return image, rotate;
}

var image2, angle = imageAugmentation(image, rotate);

console.log(angle);
cv.imshowWait('', image2);
```

error:

```
-1

C:\Users\SHAN\Desktop\Img_aug Final\test.js:20
cv.imshowWait('', image2);
   ^
Io::ImshowWait - expected arg1 to be an instance of Mat
(Use `node --trace-uncaught ...` to show where the exception was thrown)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error was can not return two values simultaneously in javascript so must return values as an array format in javascript

```
function flip(image, rotate){
    var flip_img = image.flip(1);
    var rotate = -(rotate);
    return [flip_img, rotate];
}

function imageAugmentation(image, rotate){

    var [image, rotate] = flip(image, rotate);
    return [image, rotate];
}
```